# Can't start Blender

Tags: error

Yesterday I was working just fine, but today I tried to open Blender and it closed, then I ran it on Terminal and I got this:

```
bl_locale_set(): Conversion failed 
ERROR (gpu.shader): gpu_shader_2D_widget_base FragShader: 
      | 
   81 | layout(depth_any) out float gl_FragDepth;
      |         ^
      | Error: unrecognized layout identifier `depth_any'

Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault
```

```
# Blender 3.2.0, Commit date: 2022-06-08 10:22, Hash e05e1e369187

# backtrace
/snap/blender/2474/blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x20) [0xc1491e0]
/snap/blender/2474/blender() [0x11d8e2a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x43090) [0x7fe2ad77c090]
/snap/blender/2474/blender(GPU_shader_get_builtin_uniform+0) [0xad8a590]
/snap/blender/2474/blender(GPU_matrix_bind+0x1b) [0xad8729b]
/snap/blender/2474/blender(UI_widgetbase_draw_cache_flush+0xb5) [0x23d5e65]
/snap/blender/2474/blender() [0x23d92b2]
/snap/blender/2474/blender(ui_draw_but+0xc9c) [0x23dd30c]
/snap/blender/2474/blender(UI_block_draw+0x2fe) [0x237b95e]
/snap/blender/2474/blender(UI_blocklist_draw+0x34) [0x237b9e4]
/snap/blender/2474/blender(ED_region_header_draw+0x77) [0x1c5fc27]
/snap/blender/2474/blender(ED_region_do_draw+0x841) [0x1c631c1]
/snap/blender/2474/blender(wm_draw_update+0x7a3) [0x179dd13]
/snap/blender/2474/blender(WM_main+0x30) [0x179aa40]
/snap/blender/2474/blender(main+0x322) [0x10d47e2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7fe2ad75d083]
/snap/blender/2474/blender() [0x11d570c]

# Python backtrace
```

I reinstalled Blender just in case but it didn't work, I'm using ZorinOS

Comment: Try restarting your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Blender, described in ticket https://developer.blender.org/T98708, which looks like the exact same issue described above.

Try setting the **environment variable**
**MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.1 blender**

it should work with that setting.

Also, you could try Blender 3.1.2, alternatively.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked